# Why does this happen to Kate?

Tags: plot-explanation, kate

In the 2021 movie *Kate*, why does

> Varrick

order the poisoning of Kate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Digital Spy](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a37541761/kate-ending-explained-netflix/):

> Kijima reveals to Kate that Renji and Varrick teamed up to kill Ani's father (Ani's father, her target in the first scene) because Renji was jealous and wanted to take over, and now have poisoned Kate so that she won't find out.